# Why is the branch.io iOS SDK returning error "Invalid identity_id"

Tags: branch.io

I can't find any reference to this in the docs.

The error passed to the deepLinkHandler callback is:

```
Error Domain=io.branch Code=1004 "{
    code = 400;
    message = "Invalid identity_id";
}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription={
    code = 400;
    message = "Invalid identity_id";
}}
```

I'm not sure what this means and why branch isn't picking up the details about the install link clicked as is intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that occurred last week and should be resolved now after our last update - can you check and see if this is still an issue for you or if it has been resolved?
Thanks!